# Chrome extension using React js: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension with React to implement a light/dark mode toggle for a web app. However, I'm encountering an error that I'm having trouble resolving:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist.

also I can't store data

Background code:

```js
// background.js

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
 // Set initial value for isDarkMode in local storage
 chrome.storage.local.set({ isDarkMode: false });
 toggleDarkMode();
});

// Function to toggle dark mode and send message to content script
function toggleDarkMode() {
 chrome.storage.local.get("isDarkMode", (data) => {
   const isDarkMode = data.isDarkMode || false;
   console.log(isDarkMode);
   // Broadcast the new mode to all tabs
   chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
     tabs.forEach((tab) => {
       // Check if tab is still open before sending a message
       if (tab.id && tab.url) {
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
           action: isDarkMode
             ? "switchBackgroundColorOn"
             : "switchBackgroundColorOff",
         });
       }
     });
   });
 });
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(() => {
 toggleDarkMode();
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
 if (message.action === "toggleDarkMode") {
   toggleDarkMode();
 }
});
```

One of my scripts:

```js
const switchBackgroundColorOff = () => {
  document.documentElement.style.filter = "invert(0) hue-rotate(0deg)";

  const mediaElements = document.querySelectorAll(
    "img, picture, video"
  ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;

  mediaElements.forEach((mediaItem) => {
    mediaItem.style.filter = "invert(0) hue-rotate(0deg)";
  });
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === "switchBackgroundColorOff") {
    switchBackgroundColorOff();
    chrome.storage.local.set({ isDarkMode: false });
  }
});
```

My popup call function on click:

```js
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);

  const switchBackgroundColor = () => {
    // Toggle the mode in the background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "toggleDarkMode" });
    setIsDark(() => !isDark);
  };
```

Manifest:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "js/vendor.js",
        "js/content_script.js",
        "js/content_scriptOn.js",
        "js/content_scriptOff.js"
      ]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo.png",
    "48": "logo.png",
    "128": "logo.png"
  }
}
```